# Haskell class misunderstanding

Tags: haskell

Hello i need to create a class which contains a method called `prize'` which calculates some Fractional. I want to instance in case I get an `Order`, later I will have to instance again in case I get a `[Order]`, this is the code :

```
class Ped a where
    prize' :: Fractional b => a -> b

instance (Integral n, Fractional p) => Ped (Order n p) where
    prize' x = prizeOrder x

data (Integral c,Fractional p) => Product c p
    = Prod c String p
    deriving (Show, Read) 

data (Integral n, Fractional p) => Order n p
    = PdMult (Product n p) n
    | PdUnit (Product n p)
    deriving (Show, Eq)

prize :: (Fractional p, Integral c) =>(Product c p) -> p
prize (Prod _ _ x) = x

prizeOrder :: (Fractional p, Integral c) => (Order c p) -> p
prizeOrder (PdMult p n) = (prize p) * (fromIntegral n)
prizeOrder (PdUnit p) = prize p
```

Prelude says:

```
Could not deduce (p ~ b)
from the context (Integral n, Fractional p)
bound by the instance declaration
at src\Funciones.hs:6:10-55
or from (Fractional b)
bound by the type signature for
     prize' :: Fractional b => Order n p -> b
at src\Funciones.hs:7:5-11
`p' is a rigid type variable bound by
  the instance declaration
  at src\Funciones.hs:6:10
`b' is a rigid type variable bound by
  the type signature for prize' :: Fractional b => Order n p -> b
  at src\Funciones.hs:7:5
Expected type: Order b
  Actual type: Order n p
Relevant bindings include
  x :: Order n p
    (bound at src\Funciones.hs:7:13)
  prize' :: Order n p -> b
    (bound at src\Funciones.hs:7:5)
In the first argument of `prizeOrder', namely `x'
In the expression: prizeOrder x
```

Comment: First of all, don't put class constraints on data types.  If you need that functionality there are GADTs, but it looks like that isn't the solution you need here.

Comment: The problem is that your class says: I can convert this to whatever `Fractional` you want, whereas the data clearly restricts it based on the decisions you've made.

Comment: I have done a whole big program by using them, and it works correctly, but its first time i create a class in the program :)

Comment: from the small part I can see here I wonder why you need the `Ped` class in the first place - what's wrong with `prizeOrder` by itself?

Comment: @Carsten: that's indicated by the question, one wishes for instance to provide a function with the same name for `[Order]`, for instance to sum by.

Comment: I have to create a class with one method called prize' which depending on if i use an Order or a [Order], prizeOrder only gets the first case. Plus i need to do it this way of course i know how to calculete prizeOrder[Order]

Comment: @CommuSoft yeah I've seen it - but well `sum . map prizeOrder` and stuff ... well just saying

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your `class` definition gives an additional *degree of freedom*, your `instance` fails to provide. In your class you state:

```
class Ped a where
    prize' :: Fractional b => a -> b
```

That means that the programmer could choose whatever `Fraction b` for `b` he/she wants.

Now if we look to your instance:

```
instance (Integral n, Fractional p) => Ped (Order n p) where
    prize' x = prizeOrder x
```

Here you say that `prize'` depends on `prizeOrder`. The `prizeOrder` function has however the signature:

```
prizeOrder :: (Fractional p, Integral c) => (Order c p) -> p
```

Which means you cannot choose `b` at all. If I would use `prize'` with as expected return type `Float`, that would be accepted by `Ped`, but not by a datastructure `Order Double Int`.

You can "solve" this by using *multi-parameter classes*, you take the `b` in the `class` signature:

```
class Ped a b where
    prize' :: a -> b
```

Next you need to define the instance with a second type parameter to ensure the output is `p`:

```
instance (Integral n, Fractional p) => Ped (Order n p) p where
    prize' x = prizeOrder x
```

You will need to activate some additional *GHC* features, the full code would read like:

```
{-# LANGUAGE MultiParamTypeClasses #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DatatypeContexts #-}

class Ped a b where
    prize' :: a -> b

instance (Integral n, Fractional p) => Ped (Order n p) p where
    prize' x = prizeOrder x

data (Integral c,Fractional p) => Product c p
    = Prod c String p
    deriving (Show, Read) 

data (Integral n, Fractional p) => Order n p
    = PdMult (Product n p) n
    | PdUnit (Product n p)
    deriving (Show)

prize :: (Fractional p, Integral c) =>(Product c p) -> p
prize (Prod _ _ x) = x

prizeOrder :: (Fractional p, Integral c) => (Order c p) -> p
prizeOrder (PdMult p n) = (prize p) * (fromIntegral n)
prizeOrder (PdUnit p) = prize p
```

But as said by @bheklilr, don't use "*class constraints on data types*". Furthermore one better asks his/herself whether it pays off to use a `class`.

Comment: Thank you very much, Ive tried that before but i dont know how to activate those features y copied your code and prelude tells me:
Too many parameters for class `Ped'
    (Use MultiParamTypeClasses to allow multi-parameter classes)
    In the class declaration for `Ped'

Comment: @KannaKiski: using the directives between the `{-#` and `#-}`. Those aren't comments.

Comment: I already did it, but it sais the same thing...Could it be Eclipse?

Comment: Are you using the *Glasgow Haskell Compiler (GHC)*?

Comment: Yap i use eclipse option: degug as GHCi sesion

Comment: Perhaps restart the session or search whether you can enable these options in the debugging.

Comment: @KannaKiski In GHCI, you can't turn on extensions using `LANGUAGE` pragmas. Use the `:set` command instead: `:set -XMultiParamTypeClasses` etc. I would suggest putting the code into a file and then loading it though. Have you tried that? I'm not sure how that Eclipse command works.